# sql server select rows into string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query.

```
declare @column_names varchar(1000)    
declare @result varchar(1000)

set @column_names='id,firstname,lastname,age,city,country'
set @result=''
select @result=@result+@column_names +','+from studenttable where id='1'
```

But this query returns `id,firstname,lastname,age,city,country` as result
and not like `1,john,j,21,newyork,us`.

How to change query so that `@result` will contain actual entries in comma-separated form?

Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: You will have to use dynamic sql - http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: read this http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 2):

To execute dynamic T-SQL statements use sp_executesql as:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
          N'SELECT ' +@column_names +' FROM studenttable 
          WHERE id= @id',
          N'@id tinyint',
          @id= 1;
```